# URLSession with URLCredential

Tags: swift, urlsession

I would like to get data from server, but credential (username, password. Not Basi Authentification) is necessary to get it. Therefore, I try to use URLSession with URLCredential as following:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/handling_an_authentication_challenge

However, I could not understand this document...
So could you tell me how to use URLSession with URLCredential?

I tried URLSession like:

```
    func startLoad() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.abcde-test-url.com/")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("client error: \(error.localizedDescription) \n")
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                print("no data or no response")
                return
            }
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                print(data)
            } else {
                print("error status code: \(response.statusCode)\n")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

But I couldn't understand the usage with URLCredential.

Comment: "Implement the delegate methods described in this article to answer challenges issued by a server that your app connects to. If you don’t implement a delegate, your request may be denied by the server, and you receive a response with HTTP status code 401 (Forbidden) instead of the data you expect." you need to implement the two delegate methods.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment!!
I think this is normal for lots of devloper but I don't know how to implememt the delegate...

Is it OK if you tell me a sample for this? I am so sorry.